# vmWare 5.5 , DELL EMC 4024 , Thick Provisioned Lazy Zeroed

Tags: vmware-esxi, emc

I have a small problem here understanding why is the Space Reported between EMC and vmWare off by so much.

EMC says Available Size for both pools ca. 700GB .

VMWare says for both DataStores I have 1500GB and 1600GB Free Space.

All my Hosts use Thick Provisioned Lazy Zeroed .

Is this normal ? I know that the Data on the EMC is stored differently than on the VMWare ... but who is holding the Space Back ? Is the EMC still reserving that much space even if its free?

Can this be somehow released somehow?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a hypervisor that's been EOL for 2.5 years?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-vSphere-Discussions/storage-usage-not-correct/td-p/463584

> Virtual disks in vSphere are provided as files at the storage layer
> and the file which hold the data is a binary file. This binary file do
> not change its size at will. Or, more exactly, these binary files can
> only grow (also with thin provisioned disks).
>
> If you want to reduce the size of virtual disks, you would have to
> reorganize the entire blocks within this binary file. That only
> happens with a Storage vMotion since much effort is involved in this
> operation.
>
> An example, to illustrate this behavior:
>
> You create a 100 GB thin provisioned disk and attach it to a VM. Then
> you copy 50 GB of data to that disk. In the operating system and
> vSphere you will now see a disk usage of 50 GB. Then you delete 25 GB.
> In the OS you now only see an used capacity of 25 GB. In vSphere,
> however, you see an used capacity of 50 GB since the underlying binary
> file is still 50 GB large.
>
> So, if you migrate the VM to another datastore, the size should match
> the size displayed in the OS again. At least, until it drifts apart
> again.
> --- Regards, Sebastian VCP6.5-DCV // VCP7-CMA // vSAN 2017 Specialist Please mark this answer as 'helpful' or 'correct' if you think your
> question has been answered correctly.